# Compiler errors using boost::asio/windows7/visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, boost-asio

I'm struggling since several hours trying to compile a boost::asio program on my system (win7, vs2010, boost 1.49). Boost has been properly builed and linked to my vs project. I made a test run with boost::regex and everything worked ok.

The compiler complain about 2 headers (in6addr.h, ws2ipdef.h), about 90% being C2146 (syntax) and C2079 (undefined class/struc/union name) errors.

A large amount of these errors relate to windows type definition (USHORT,ULONG...) and winsock definition(SOCKET_ADDRESS, ADDRESS_FAMILY) being undefined. A sample can be found at the end of this post.

My includes are the following:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
```

- I tried both file by file include definition and to gather up those
  in the precompiled header.
- Given that my problem seems related to winsock2 and windows
  definitions, i tried to include them in all possible ways using
  appropriate defineds (WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN..) an declaration order to
  no avail.
- I tried running winsock2 in a stand alone program and everything runned ok.

My problem seem awfully similar to this one (tried out all advices / question unresolved):

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d585193/c-cpp/cpp/bibliotheques/boost/asio-erreur-syntaxe-specificateur-type-manquant-d/

I've already broke 2 keyboards and seriously consider hanging myself with whats left of my mouse. Please help!

Thanks in advance for your time.

Thomas

Error sample:

**ws2ipdef.h**

> Erreur    171 error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : ')'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 336 1   asioProto
>   Erreur    180 error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : ')'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 354 1   asioProto
>   Erreur    189 error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : ')'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 372 1   asioProto
>   Erreur    198 error C2059: erreur de syntaxe : ')'    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 390 1   asioProto
>   Erreur    18  error C2079: 'sockaddr_gen::Address' utilise une struct de
>   'sockaddr' non défini c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 75  1   asioProto Erreur    19  error
>   C2079: 'sockaddr_gen::AddressIn' utilise une struct de 'sockaddr_in'
>   non défini    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 76  1   asioProto Erreur    177 error
>   C2086: 'int BOOLEAN' : redéfinition   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 354 1   asioProto Erreur    186 error
>   C2086: 'int BOOLEAN' : redéfinition   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2ipdef.h 372 1   asioProto

**in6addr.h**

> Erreur    7   error C2143: erreur de syntaxe : absence de ';' avant
>   '*'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\in6addr.h  27  1   asioProto Erreur    1   error
>   C2146: erreur de syntaxe : absence de ';' avant l'identificateur
>   'Byte'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\in6addr.h  24  1   asioProto Erreur    4   error
>   C2146: erreur de syntaxe : absence de ';' avant l'identificateur
>   'Word'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\in6addr.h  25  1   asioProto Erreur    2   error
>   C4430: spécificateur de type manquant - int est pris en compte par
>   défaut. Remarque : C++ ne prend pas en charge int par
>   défaut    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\in6addr.h  24  1   asioProto Erreur    3   error
>   C4430: spécificateur de type manquant - int est pris en compte par
>   défaut. Remarque : C++ ne prend pas en charge int par
>   défaut    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\in6addr.h  24  1   asioProto Erreur    5   error
>   C4430: spécificateur de type manquant - int est pris en compte par
>   défaut. Remarque : C++ ne prend pas en charge int par
>   défaut    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\in6addr.h  25  1   asioProto

Comment: where is the [reproducer](http://sscce.org/)? Also, it would be helpful if your compiler error messages are in [English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/148504).

Comment: Duly noted for the next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to nail it. Kind of.

Problem lied with the VS toolset used for compilation (v100 by default on VS2010).
When switched do v90 or SDK 7.1, compile ok.

Not sure why though.

Project properties > general > platform toolset

[C++ Native Multi-Targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx)